# What's the best open PHP newsletter manager?

Tags: php, open-source, spam-prevention, newsletter

I'm looking for a nice newsletter management solution. I tried CCmail a good script, but where I can't imort usernames!

I would like to find a system that is able to import Opt-in lists in the following format:

```
John Smith;Jsmith@johnny.com;other paramaeters...;[like] ;Male;Age...
```

I will develop my own module if I could find another emailing manager.

Are you already satisfied with a similar application with a trusted (spam-prevention) emailer?

Comment: This should be on superuser.com

Answer (score 4):

http://www.phplist.com is considered one of the best

Comment: Sorry, but PHPList struck me as a terrible piece of junk. Bad markup, bad code, broken install,.... I did a full install two times, and ran away screaming both times.

Comment: @Pekka Well, it's code is disgusting, no objections here. But it works as I know.

Comment: fair enough - I turned away after seeing the buggy UI. Sadly, the market for good PHP based newsletter tools isn't big (unlike for, say, Blogs)

Comment: @Pekka Yea... UI is templated and thus customizable.

Comment: I don't like _phplist_ -- it is full of "spaghetti code" issues not to mention PHP ugliness. [Dada-mail](https://github.com/justingit/dada-mail) appears to be mature and well maintained.

Comment: @Onlyjob Can't agree more about spaghetti code. Will look into Dada-mail. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I find [Tellmatic](http://tellmatic.org/) quite good.

Comment: The interface is some outdated. They should use Twitter Bootstrap, or something similar.

Comment: @Fedir: If you look at the date of my answer, you'll see it was posted 4 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a roundup - *[Best Open Source Email Marketing Software Roundup](http://www.greepit.com/best-open-source-email-marketing-software-roundup/)*.

Comment: Link not working anymore

Answer (score 1):

I have good experiences with WP Autoresponder. It's a WordPress plugin, not a newsletter manager on itself, but you can configure WordPress as a 'single page' for newsletter subscription