# email newsletter software

Tags: php, oop, email, newsletter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the best Open Php newsletter manager ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570943/whats-the-best-open-php-newsletter-manager)

Hi,

I am looking for a open source email newsletter software implemented in OO PHP.
I found some like phplist etc but they dont seem to use OO features.
mailchimp doesnt use Database.

Could anyone point me to any open source emailnewsletter/mail management software in OO PHP and which uses MySQL database.

Thanks

Comment: *(related)* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570943/whats-the-best-open-php-newsletter-manager

Answer (score 1):

I think this one will fit your needs.

It's open source and uses MySQL DB.

http://www.openemm.org/

Comment: It uses MySQL . But I need OO PHP based implementation.Let me know if you know any application with these requirements.